# dataframe remove last digit from string if it is number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

python dataframe

I want to delete the last character if it is number.

from current dataframe

```
data = {'d':['AAA2', 'BB 2', 'C', 'DDD ', 'EEEEEEE)', 'FFF ()', np.nan, '123456']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

to new dataframe

```
data = {'d':['AAA2', 'BB 2', 'C', 'DDD ', 'EEEEEEE)', 'FFF ()', np.nan, '123456'],
        'expected': ['AAA', 'BB', 'C', 'DDD', 'EEEEEEE)', 'FFF (', np.nan, '12345']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

ex

Answer (score 2):

Using `.str.replace`:

```
df['d'] = df['d'].str.replace(r'(\d)$','',regex=True)
```